HTTP 409 Error while traffic is routed through GCP load balancer
I'm fairly new to IT so apologize if I sound n00b.
Our goal is to have an application load balancer in GCP routing traffic from client VDIs to 4 servers in the backend. Here's what we've found so far:

When we exclude the load balancer and route client traffic directly to a server, everything works as expected
When we do client traffic --> GCP ALB --> 4 servers in backend, clients get a HTTP 409 error on "POST", then the connection is terminated
We thought it may be a session affinity issue, so we changed to client traffic --> GCP ALB --> 1 server in backend, but we still got the same 409 error

Upon checking logs in GCP, the error occurs when POST is called on one particular URL, while there are many other successful POST requests. We are thinking this has to be something related to the load balancer setup, since we don't see any issue when load balancer is not used, but we are at our wits end on what to change to fix it. Any thoughts or suggestions is much appreciated!
Summarizing the three setups we've tried:

Client --> servers (no issue, everything works)
Client --> GCP ALB --> 4 servers in backend (409 on POST to a particular url)
Client --> GCP ALB --> 1 server in backend (409 on POST to a particular url)


If you do a GET do you also get a 409 by using the LB?

No, no error on all other requests
